# How can i compare the similar images in my database before the user uploading? (java)

Tags: java, ajax, json, jsp, servlets

I have some big problems and I wish someone can help me.

I want to compare the image before the user uploads the image.
If this image has the same images in database,the user can not upload it.

I know how to compare two pictures .
My question is  how can i write the code to compare if this image doesn't upload.
I want to compare it in the first time.
And if it doesn't have the same images then the user can upload it.

My English is not well.I hope you can understand what i say. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should compute a hashCode like for the image on the client side and compare only the code with the hashCodes of the images stored on the server side. I would use SHA-1 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) as a hash function.

Comment: To be specific... You'll need a database of hashcodes for all uploaded images on the server side and your upload would then be a two step process.  Compute the hash code on the client side and send it to the server, search for the hash in the DB and allow the upload and then add the hash to the DB if there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

for a first few checks I would try to compare:

- file metadata stored in your database (if any) like: combination of fileName, filesize and fileFormat

This will help you eliminate some of the cases easily. If the comparison still returns equality then you could go ahead with @dan 's solution